# Question regarding aparent position and velocity of an object

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, observers, measurements

A time lag is always involved while observing objects. Due to this reason we can never observe the correct position of an object at a particular time. We will see it where it was some times ago. Is there any way to predict the observed position of an object at different places. For example let's consider an electron suddenly starts moving with v velocity at a particular direction.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all coordinate systems are designed to indicate the location of an event "now" even though a particular observer may not actually see that event until some later time. To calculate what the observer actually sees you have to add light travel times according to the distance of the observer from the event. When you do that, optical illusions occur which do not reflect what is physically happening. For example, the jets emanating from a black hole when observed from a distance can appear to moving faster than the speed of light.

[See this Wikipedia article on apparent superluminal motion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion)

A phenomena called [Terrell rotation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTY74hYdG4s) is another example, where taking light travel times into account gives rise to the apparent rotation of a fast moving object even though it does not actually physically rotate. If a photograph is taken of a sphere moving at great speed relative to the camera, it gives the illusion that no length contraction occurs. However, if the object photographed is a long thin rod, then the length contraction can in principle be photographed.

The simplest example of distance of the observer from the object giving rise to an optical illusion is comparing the height of two identical objects where one is near and the other is far away. The far away object appears smaller even though in reality it is not.

It is for these reasons, that most normal coordinate systems ignore light travel times.

Answer (score 0):

For uniform acceleration of a mass, the equations of motion will give you the position and velocity of the object at a given time instant. For non uniform acceleration, you can still have equations describing a particle's motion, but these cannot be defined as similar for all non uniformly accelerated particles (eg: $a=-w²x$, $v=5x$, etc). 
I should point out that you chose an electron for your example, whose motion is discontinuous and random, far from the classical, orderly motion we deal with. Were there a ball moving with speed $v$, its motion could have been described, yes.

Comment: Can you help me to derive an expression for my example.

Comment: @Name: Does it have uniform acceleration? Zero acceleration? Non uniform acceleration? Or any external forces like friction?

Comment: 0 acceleration. at first let us consider that case

Comment: Then $x=x_0+vt$, where $v$ is the constant velocity of the object and $x_0$ is its starting position. If there is motion in a plane/3D space instead of a line, similar equations can be created for y and z axes also.

Comment: I calculated that the speed of a photon will appear to be c/2 if it moves away from an observer in 1D. Is that correct?

Comment: Why c/2? Is the observer stationary, or not?

Comment: Stationary WRT what do you mean?

Comment: Stationary w.r.t. ground?

Comment: What is ground?

Comment: Ground frame is one in which observer is at rest w.r.t. earth. I think you ought to study reference frames before going into kinematics.

Comment: @Stitu I dont need to learn anymore about refference framed . Instead I think you need to learn about special relativity because speed of light is c in any frame whether it is stationary wrt earth or Mars.

Comment: I know that. I'm saying, how did you calculate it to be c/2? Also, are you active in chatrooms? This discussion would be better off there.

Comment: Yes you can create chatroom I am active there?

Comment: Alright, can you find "Discussion between Stuti and Name" there?

Comment: In the search option?

Comment: In the "filter rooms" search bar.

Comment: @Name are you still interested in discussing this further?

Answer (score 0):

Because of finite speed of light, the apparent position of illuminated object shifts, it differs from its current position (light-time correction). The displacement of the apparent position of illuminated object is also called aberration of light.

However,  electromagnetic force of attraction does not experience aberration. So, [electromagnetic force exerted by the field of the moving charged sphere on the test particle at time t is directed toward the position of the sphere at the same time t](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath562/kmath562.htm). This is a natural consequence of Lorentz covariance, and does not imply any instantaneous transfer of energy or information.